# How can I run a PowerShell script with white spaces in the path from the command line?

Tags: powershell, cmd, scripting

So I've tried a bunch of different ways to run a PowerShell script from the command line and every single one returns an error.

Here is this path:

```
C:\Users\test\Documents\test\line space\PS Script\test.ps1
```

I've tried these:

```
powershell -File '"C:\Users\test\Documents\test\line space\PS Script\test.ps1"'

powershell "& ""C:\Users\test\Documents\test\line space\PS Script\test.ps1"""

Powershell "& 'C:\Users\test\Documents\test\line space\PS Script\test.ps1'"

Powershell -File 'C:\Users\test\Documents\test\line space\PS Script\test.ps1'"
```

I get all these errors:

> & : The term 'C:\Users\test\Documents\test\line space\PS Script' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

> Processing -File ''C:\Users\test\Documents\test\line space\PS Script'' failed: The given path's format is not support ed. Specify a valid path for the -File parameter.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why are you running it from cmd?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your examples, you're mixing quotes and double quoting for no reason.

```
IF EXIST "C:\Users\test\Documents\test\line space\PS Script\test.ps1" (
  powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "C:\Users\test\Documents\test\line space\PS Script\test.ps1"
)
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, the script didn't trigger. I tried running just this part: powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File 'C:\Users\test\Documents\test\line space\PS Script\test.ps1' and got this error: 
 The given path's format is not supported.

Comment: @Awsmike Try removing the single-quotes and see what happens

Comment: Processing -File C:\Users\test\Documents\test\line space\PS Script\test.ps1 failed because the file does not have a '.ps1' extension. Specify a valid Windows PowerShell script file name, and then try again.

Comment: Alright, so it is interpreting the spaces as extra arguments to the file.  Is the path valid in the first place? @Awsmike

Comment: Your original answer with double quotes instead of single quotes actually worked!

Answer (score 56):

## The `-File` parameter

If you want to run `powershell.exe -File` from the command line, you always have to set paths with spaces in double quotes (`"`). Single quotes (`'`) are only recognized by PowerShell. But as powershell.exe is invoked (and hence the file parameter processed) by the command line, you have to use `"`.

```
powershell.exe -File "C:\Users\test\Documents\Test Space\test.ps1" -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

## The `-Command` parameter

If you use the `-Command` parameter, instead of `-File`, the `-Command` content is processed by PowerShell. Hence you can - and in this case have to - use `'` inside `"`.

```
powershell.exe -Command "& 'C:\Users\test\Documents\Test Space\test.ps1'" -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

The double quotes are processed by the command line, and `& 'C:\Users\test\Documents\Test Space\test.ps1'` is a command that is actually processed by PowerShell.

Solution 1 is obviously simpler.

Note that `-Command` is also the default parameter that is used, if you do not specify any.

```
powershell.exe "& 'C:\Users\test\Documents\Test Space\test.ps1'" -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

This would work, too.

## The `-EncodedCommand` parameter

You can encode your command as [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). This solves many "quoting" issues and is sometimes (but not in your case though) the only possible way.

First you have to create the encoded command

```
$Command = "& 'C:\Users\test\Documents\Test Space\test.ps1'"
[Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($Command))
```

And then you can use the the `-EncodedCommand` parameter like this

```
powershell.exe -EncodedCommand JgAgACcAQwA6AFwAVQBzAGUAcgBzAFwAdABlAHMAdABcAEQAbwBjAHUAbQBlAG4AdABzAFwAVABlAHMAdAAgAFMAcABhAGMAZQBcAHQAZQBzAHQALgBwAHMAMQAnAA== -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

Comment: Nicely done; as an aside: in PowerShell _Core_, `-File` is now the default (this change was necessary to support Unix shebang lines).

Comment: I feel like this is a better answer than the accepted answer. Just putting file path in quotes using -file parameter didn't work at all for me.

Answer (score 35):

Try this:

```
& "C:\Users\test\Documents\test\line space\PS Script\test"
```

Comment: He's trying to use `cmd`, so I'm assuming he's invoking it from a `.cmd` or `.bat` file.  The PS Invoke (`&`) operator won't do any good for him.

Comment: PS C:\> & "C:\Temp\Folder with Whitespaces\SomeApp.exe" /switchA valA /switchB valB will work in PowerShell if the ampersand is used as prefix.  Without the ampersand, it will error out.  For a DOS console, the ampersand is not required.  I think this is where C.Hennessey was going.

Comment: ah... ampersand...Exactly what I was looking for 

Comment: This question shows up on google even when searching for how to run a ps script in powershell, that's why this answer is relevant (for those wondering)

Comment: Sometimes you need to run programs on the command line with parameters, and this approach work.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to pass *a parameter* with spaces.

I am dragging and dropping a file onto a batch file, and the file is off on the server with spaces in the path and/or file name.  After testing the above answers, I got this to work.  Note I am changing to the working directory prior to starting the PowerShell executable.

Batch file:

```
pushd O:\Data\QuickList
start powershell -noexit -Command ".\QuickList.ps1 -datafile '%1'"
popd
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you use parameters you can do as follows.

```
powershell.exe -command "& {&'C:\A B C\foo.ps1' param1 param2}"
```

Thanks at this point to [a blog post by Hesham A. Amin](https://blog.heshamamin.com/2009/04/calling-powershell-script-in-path-with.html) :-)