# How do I patch SharePoint using PowerShell remote (WinRM)?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, scheduled-tasks, powershell-remoting, windows-update

Thera are **a lot** of material about patching Windows using PowerShell. And some about patching remotely.
When optimizing/stabilizing patches for SharePoint they should be applied in separate batches.

1. OS Patches
2. SQL Patches
3. SharePoint Patches

To greatly ease the selection of patches to apply, I'm using the module [PS Gallery - PSWindowsUpdate](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSWindowsUpdate).

However, most of the patches for SharePoint has to be run interactively, which is possible using `Scheduled Tasks`. But that normally requires a user with the appropriate permissions to already be logged in locally, which defies the purpose of remote scripting :/

But I remembered setting [`S4U`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/taskschedulerschema-logontype-principaltype-element), Service For User, that should bypass that requirement. However, I can't seem to find the correct params to use.

I do think `S4U` is blocked from accessing the network (although other sources states otherwise), so I have tried to make sure the patches are downloaded beforehand. Either by using the built-in `WindowsUpdateProvider` or `PSWindowsUpdate`.

The account used for running the scheduled task of course also need the system privilege `Logon as batch job`.

One thing that might trip things up in my case is that legacy RPC has to be kept disabled throughout the network.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteSrv -ScriptBlock {
  $SoftwareUpdates = Start-WUScan -SearchCriteria "Type='Software' AND IsInstalled =0"
  Install-WUUpdates -Updates $SoftwareUpdates -DownloadOnly $true | Out-Null

  $Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date).AddYears(10)

  $Argument = "Install-WindowsUpdate -NotCategory 'Microsoft SQL Server','Office Online Server' -AcceptAll -AutoReboot"

  $Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument "$Argument"

  $Principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal `
    -UserId 'domain\userid' `
    -RunLevel Highest `
    -LogonType S4U

  Register-ScheduledTask `
    -TaskPath '\SharePoint\' -TaskName 'PatchSharePoint' `
    -Trigger $Trigger `
    -Principal $Principal `
    -Action $Action `
    -Force | Out-Null

  Start-ScheduledTask -TaskPath '\SharePoint\' -TaskName 'PatchSharePoint'
}
```

The patches requiring interactive logon still isn't applied. But the `Action Completed` in the Task Scheduler history states.

```
Task Scheduler successfully completed task "\SharePoint\PatchSharePoint", instance "{...},  
action "PowerShell.exe" with return code 0.
```

Edit: Fixed typo in Argument.

Comment: Instead of trying to start the task remotely, schedule it to run a minute or two in the future. Iirc, you can kick those off remotely due to a security design

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343993/batch-file-from-scheduled-task-returns-code-2147942401

Comment: @DougMaurer And that is what I'm doing as far as I can tell.

Comment: @rinatgadeev I've already got `logon as batch job` privileges.

Comment: Using [JEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078958/powershell-remote-microsoft-update-session-access-denied-0x80070005/60046097#60046097) actually took me a little further down the road.

Comment: Using JEA remote seems to trigger the double-hop issue.

Comment: You see that command called start scheduled task? That is you trying to start the task remotely. I’m saying schedule it to run on its own in the future. Do NOT start it yourself, that’s my suggestion.

Comment: @DougMaurer No. The process scheduled do start, se simplified example below.

Comment: All your examples i see contain start-scheduledtask.  If you don’t want to try the suggestion, that’s fine. Take care.

Comment: Yes, and that is done within the remote session as in "locally". You can very easy verify the effect by simply running the simple example is the answer below your self :)

Comment: You’re not understanding. You are still executing that local command remotely. And as I stated, I recall that being blocked by a security design. Hence I suggested you just try letting it start itself. This is specific to pswindowsupdate module

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there is actually no issue with starting tasks requiring interactive sessions using Scheduled Tasks, S4U.

This example works just fine...

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteSrv -ScriptBlock {

  $Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date).AddYears(10)

  $Argument = "mmc.exe"

  $Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument "$Argument"

  $Principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal `
    -UserId 'domain\userid' `
    -RunLevel Highest `
    -LogonType S4U

  Register-ScheduledTask `
    -TaskPath '\PoC\' -TaskName 'StarMMC' `
    -Trigger $Trigger `
    -Principal $Principal `
    -Action $Action `
    -Force | Out-Null

  Start-ScheduledTask -TaskPath '\PoC\' -TaskName 'StartMMC'
}
```

The MMC won't be run interactive with the desktop of the user of course. That was never the intention. But it will start.

I don't even need a scheduled task. This will also start a process that requires Interactive privileges.

```
Enter-PSSession RemoteSrv
[RemoteSrv] mmc.exe
```

Or I'm I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the solutions I've found for patching SharePoint remotely is based on PSExec or direct downloads of the CU, instead of using WUAU, such as [GitHub - SharePoint Patchify](https://github.com/spjeff/sppatchify).