# Execute a powershell file with an absolute path that contains spaces

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess

I'm trying to execute a `ps1` file in my python script.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", 'F:/FOLDER/FOLDER OK/myfile.ps1'])
```

It stopped at `F:/FOLDER/FOLDER` so I added additional quotes like this:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", '"F:/FOLDER/FOLDER OK/myfile.ps1"'])
```

No error now, but it didn't execute the script either...
Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a powershell script with white spaces in path from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760457/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-with-white-spaces-in-path-from-command-line)

Comment: windows sucks so much sometimes. Have you tried the following workaround: `proc = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", 'myfile.ps1'],cwd='F:/FOLDER/FOLDER OK')` ?

Comment: @Mark - definitely relevant, but not a duplicate.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre didn't work :/ no error nothing, it just didn't execute the file

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Answer is there. Use `-File` and it will work. This isn't a Python-specific issue or anything from what it seems.

Comment: @Mark - agreed that the relevant information is there, and that the querent should be able to derive my answer below from it, but the next person might not; that's why I say 'relevant, but not duplicate'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`powershell.exe` does not assume that a parameter is automatically a file to execute; you need to identify all parameters. Use the `-File` switch

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", "-File", r"F:\FOLDER\FOLDER OK\myfile.ps1"])
```

<sup>The `r` in `r"..."` (for *raw*) turns off escape-sequence processing so that `\` can be used without escaping.</sup>

See [PowerShell Command Line Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help?view=powershell-6) at Microsoft Docs.

```
PowerShell[.exe]
       [-Command { - | <script-block> [-args <arg-array>]
                     | <string> [<CommandParameters>] } ]
       [-EncodedCommand <Base64EncodedCommand>]
       [-ExecutionPolicy <ExecutionPolicy>]
       [-File <FilePath> [<Args>]]
       [-InputFormat {Text | XML}] 
       [-Mta]
       [-NoExit]
       [-NoLogo]
       [-NonInteractive] 
       [-NoProfile] 
       [-OutputFormat {Text | XML}] 
       [-PSConsoleFile <FilePath> | -Version <PowerShell version>]
       [-Sta]
       [-WindowStyle <style>]
```

Comment: As an aside: PowerShell _Core_ now _defaults_ to `-File`, (thought it never hurts to be explicit; the change was necessary to support Unix shebang lines).